# factor tags in when detecting duplicate titles

Tags: feature-request, title

I tried to edit a typo in the title of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121877/invalid-cat-exception#15121877), but I got an error saying

> a question with that title already exists

The problem is that the question that already had the title, [used a different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724950/invalid-cast-exception)

These seem to be okay titles (they're the name of the particular .net exception) but considering that they're different languages, I'd say that the questions are at least slightly different or will attract different potential answers.

Is it possible for tags to be factored in when detecting duplicate question titles?

Comment: The titles on both questions seem to be useless, in my opinion. I would rather prefer a meaningful title that might help others in future.

Comment: @Siva When someone is searching for a solution to their problem, they're likely to be searching for the particular error message.  IMHO Posting the error message is not only useful, but I'd go as far to say that it's Optimal.

Comment: invalid Cat exception is hardly an error message

Comment: Error message alone is not useful. You need the context in which the it occurred. The same error could be triggered by multiple different reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those really *aren't* good titles, and just considering the major tag doesn't help them a whole lot. They need to be edited for de-duplication.

You're absolutely right that error messages should be present verbatim in a question because they're good (even optimal) search targets, but there still needs to be more information than that in the title.

When you come up with six different "CatVomitError: you will need a new couch" questions in your Google results, the major tag is already prepended to the titles, so that information is available to searchers. The thing is, even error message plus language/framework is not particularly definitive -- there's usually a few different ways to get the same message, meaning you have to click through anyways to see if your exact situation matches.

The OP (or an editor with more expertise in the subject) should be able to add something along the lines of "...when trying to stir the oatmeal", or "...but I'm not using a garden hose", or "...even though the red button was already pushed" which will a) instantly make the title unique, and b) make it way more useful to searchers.

In short, the tag doesn't make the title much more specific, which is the goal of the prohibition on duplicate titles. The title needs some meat to it other than one more technical word, and leaving the restriction as it is furthers that goal.

Answer (score 2):

The title should be kept unique. It is a bad title in the example question anyway. It does not say anything useful.

And we already have so many questions with lousy title, why make it easier to post them by just using different tags? Do we really want to have *I need your help with this* titles for every tag permutation?