# Duplicate Question Titles

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, title

The ban on duplicate question titles is bad.

In some circumstances, for example if your environment is giving you an unfortunate error, the error is simply not specific enough to be more specific in the question title. I could give a silly example of a compiler where every error is just "Error". The output of our hypothetical compiler does not contain any more information than the questioner has given in the title. The only thing that differentiates them is the sample code in the question body.

What, precisely, is the questioner intended to do to be more specific to disambiguate his question from all of the other questions asking about the identical error? So far, I've mostly seen people just re-phrase the same error text in very slightly different ways, which is of course completely unhelpful to everybody, and circumvents the ban without giving prospective answerers any more information.

Edit: I'm really feeling the "RARGH, Questioners should put in efforts!" from the answers. Here's a hint: *if you put in the effort, you don't always get a result that's going to fit in a title*. A title is only a few words long, you can't put in your life story.

Comment: Can you provide an example where: 1. the two questions are different, and 2. they could both use the same _useful_ title? Because, honestly, the only scenarios I can envision where two different questions would logically have the same title is when it would be a really crappy title.

Comment: Don't you remember? We're supposed to have all the tags in the title now. That surely eliminates all valid dupes.

Comment: Closely related: [Factor tags in when detecting duplicate titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169400)

Answer (score 11):

And letting them create duplicate titles is going to give answerers more information *how* exactly?

By *blocking* dupe titles, we at least give question askers a clear signal they need to think about their title better. They need to look at those duplicate questions, and figure out how their question is *different*. If there are no answers to those questions, then their question with the *same title* won't get any answers either, and they should use different means to get those other questions answered. If their question is different, they get a chance to update their question title to show that.

And how do you know how many *great* titles did we get after someone first was blocked from using a duplicate title? Don't just look at those titles that try to circumvent the test by rephrasing the title in bad ways. People that do that already are a lost cause, if they don't put in the effort to create a better title, what must their actual question be like.

Comment: It won't. But it will mean they don't have to dick around trying to find an exact wording that wasn't already used. The questioner *doesn't have anything more to put in the title*. As I asked in the question, what would you actually really suggest questioners do when the title already contains all the information they have?

Comment: @DeadMG: Oh come on, if that is really the case then it is a dupe. A question title can contain more than just the error message..

Comment: Yeah, because no error can have more than one cause, and every questioner (who needs help with the error) can immediately spot the cause in everybody else who had that error. And you can always list everything you know it isn't in a really short title.

Comment: Blocking them from creating a dupe question title is *not* going to make that situation any better. Why exactly would we have to suffer an endless parade of `SyntaxError: my code doesn't run` titles here? I don't think the situation where you *genuinely* cannot put anything more meaningful in the title of the question happens often enough (if at all) to warrant lifting the block.

Comment: You're not helping anything by banning it, except making asking less convenient. I was under the impression that making asking less convenient was something where you had to actually derive some other benefit from it.

Comment: @DeadMG: We want to make asking **quality** questions convenient. We don't want to make dumping every little problem you ever encounter convenient. We do ask that the question asker has put in his homework first, and that, unfortunately, is rather inconvenient for the fire-and-forget type of question asker. And that is a *good* thing.

Comment: You assume that if you put in the homework, you *always* get a useful result that is going to fit in the very short space of a title. That assumption is flawed.

Comment: No, I am not making any such assumptions. From experience I know that **not** putting in the homework greatly reduces your chances of getting a result. Don't turn my words around, that doesn't work.

Comment: @DeadMG: You do know the length allowances for the title are rather generous, right? I find myself cutting down overly verbose titles on a regular basis.

Comment: There's a really big difference between "generous" and "Every difference between my source and the source I saw on other questions that were answered". Not to mention that would be a big information duplicate since anyone answering could just read the question if the source sample is small

Comment: Perhaps you should add some concrete examples to your question. I am *highly* skeptical this is really a problem.

Answer (score 9):

> What, precisely, is the questioner intended to do to be more specific to disambiguate his question from all of the other questions asking about the identical error?

They're supposed to read the answers to those other questions to see if they don't actually need to post a new question at all.  If they don't find an already existing answer, they should (in the process) figure out how their question is different from the similar questions, and post a question with a more specific title.

Comment: What if the other questions are unanswered? Also, a ten-word title totally has room for everything you can figure out it's not.

Comment: @DeadMG Then skip to "If they don't find an already existing answer..."

Comment: If I have a ten-word title, then I probably already used six or seven just to describe the problem. How big, exactly, do you intend for me to make it so I can describe everything I figured out that it isn't by finding other answers that didn't apply?

Answer (score 3):

#### The ban on duplicate question titles is good.

- If it's a duplicate question, then rephrasing the title in multiple ways is a *good* thing for seo.
- If it's not  a duplicate, effort should be made *by the OP* to disambiguate.

Comment: You assume that the OP has information with which to disambiguate.

Comment: I definitely think they *should* spent time working out how it's different, if they can't see why it's different how can we anyone be expected to answer?

Comment: Who says that information fits in a title?

Comment: All the information doesn't (that's why there is a content box) but I don't think it's not too much to ask OP to think of one or two words (they can always be edited later if they were a bad choice).

Answer (score 2):

> I could give a silly example of a compiler where every error is just "Error".

Possible question titles for questions about errors from your compiler:

> Getting "Error" from DeadMG's Super Verbose Compiler in my for loop
>
> Message "Error" when compiling libpng with DMGSVC
>
> Compilation stops with "Error" at pointer dereference

A plain error message **isn't a good enough title by itself** with or without the duplicate title restriction. There should always be some more information ("...except the carrot *is* purple.", "Streams are definitely crossed but...", "When I try to put butter on my cat..."). That info shouldn't require heroic effort on the part of the questioner -- it's just a quick description of the circumstances of the error, but it immediately differentiates the title, and more importantly the *question* in search results.